# People API not creating birthday when date object is passed

Tags: google-people-api

I want to create a contact where I need to create entry in birthday calendar. Hence I am using people API to create a birthday date

I am following this documentation https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.Birthday

[Click here to open the API builder](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact?apix_params=%7B%22personFields%22%3A%22names%2Cbirthdays%2CphoneNumbers%2Cmemberships%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22phoneNumbers%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22work%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22(266)%20581-6706%22%7D%5D%2C%22names%22%3A%5B%7B%22unstructuredName%22%3A%22Bradley%22%7D%5D%2C%22birthdays%22%3A%5B%7B%22date%22%3A%7B%22year%22%3A2012%2C%22month%22%3A10%2C%22day%22%3A13%7D%7D%5D%2C%22memberships%22%3A%5B%7B%22contactGroupMembership%22%3A%7B%22contactGroupResourceName%22%3A%22contactGroups%2FmyContacts%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D)

personFields are set to

```
names,birthdays,phoneNumbers,memberships
```

I am passing the person object as

```
{
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "work",
      "value": "(266) 581-6706"
    }
  ],
  "names": [
    {
      "unstructuredName": "Bradley"
    }
  ],
  "birthdays": [
    {
      "date": {
        "year": 2012,
        "month": 10,
        "day": 13
      }
    }
  ],
  "memberships": [
    {
      "contactGroupMembership": {
        "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/myContacts"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But the API does create a date with `"text": "10/13/2021"` which is of no use since this method will not create entries in birthday calendar. I am expecting the date object to be passed. Could anyone tell me, Whether I am missing something

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:createContact?personFields=names%2Cbirthdays%2CphoneNumbers%2Cmemberships&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"phoneNumbers":[{"type":"work","value":"(266) 581-6706"}],"names":[{"unstructuredName":"Bradley"}],"birthdays":[{"date":{"year":2012,"month":10,"day":13}}],"memberships":[{"contactGroupMembership":{"contactGroupResourceName":"contactGroups/myContacts"}}]}' \
  --compressed
```

Answer (score 1):

### There is a new [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/200184636) affecting the setting of birthdays

I suggest you to "star" it to increase visibility, so that it hopefully will be fixed faster.